# how to add difference between datetime in a loop php?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get the average between all created time and changedon time,so I have to get the difference at each row and add it, I tried the following code but it's not working and I don't know why as I tried each statement individually and worked well

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $changedon = new DateTime($row['changedon']);
    $createdtime = new DateTime($row['createdtime']);

    if ($i == 0) {
        $total_time = $createdtime->diff($changedon);
        $i++;
    } else {
        $total_time->add($createdtime->diff($changedon));
    }
}

echo $total_time->format('%y years %m months %a days %h hours %i minutes %s seconds');
```

Comment: did you forget to divide by the number of records?

Comment: is it really related to all those php versions?

Comment: It doesn't show the total yet !!

Comment: No but I really need help as I asked to just php but no one replied me

Comment: adding all those php version will probably make people less inclined to click on the question; a lot of people make a point of ignoring questions that are specific to obsolete versions so may filter out your question if it has php5.2 tag for example (even 5.5 is technically obsolete today). Try tagging with terms like 'datetime' instead.

Comment: Make sure to initialise the `$i` counter variable at the start of your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DateInterval` is not suitable to calculate averages. You will have to do some calculations yourself. This could be a starting point:

```
$createdSeconds = 0;
$changedSeconds = 0;
$items = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $changedon = new DateTime($row['changedon']);
    $createdtime = new DateTime($row['createdtime']);
    $createdSeconds += $createdtime->getTimestamp();
    $changedSeconds += $changedon->getTimestamp();
    $items++;
}
printf(
    'Average time between create and change is %d seconds',
    ($changedSeconds - $createdSeconds) / $items
);
```

Comment: My bad, I should have used `printf()` instead of `sprintf()`. Updated the code. `printf()` outputs, [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) returns. In this case the `%d` is replaced with a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addtime($time1,$time2)
{
$x = new DateTime($time1);
$y = new DateTime($time2);

$interval1 = $x->diff(new DateTime('00:00:00')) ;
$interval2 = $y->diff(new DateTime('00:00:00')) ;

$e = new DateTime('00:00');
$f = clone $e;
$e->add($interval1);
$e->add($interval2);
$total = $f->diff($e)->format("%H:%I:%S");
return $total;
}
```

Comment: i'm already doing that but I want to add the result of this subtraction !

Comment: Ok sorry about this, check the answer again there is a function who can do this